# Error when running docker and maven from shell script

Tags: bash, docker, shell, maven, unix

I can run the following line from the command line with correct results:

```
docker run --rm  -v $PWD/java-app:/app -v /root/.m2/:/root/.m2/ -w /app maven:3-alpine  mvn -B -DskipTests clean package
```

Based on the previous command, I created the following script:

```
echo "******************"
echo "***Building jar***"
echo "******************"
docker run --rm  -v $PWD/java-app:/app -v /root/.m2/:/root/.m2/ -w /app maven:3-alpine  "$@"
```

To run that script, I use the following line:

```
./jenkins/build/mvn.sh mvn -B -DskipTests package
```

And I obtain the following output:

```
******************
***Building jar***
******************
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.071 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-21T19:03:56Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/381M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "package
[ERROR] ". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

The reason was I was creating the script with a Windows editor. That introduced a bad character in the file.